# OpenX rest api - get list of sites under publisher

Tags: api, rest, xml-rpc, openx

I'm trying to find a method to fetch all sites under publisher using OpenX rest API.
However documentation (http://www.openx.com/docs/openx_help_center/content/index.html) does not offer any insight in "filtering" results per publisher id (account_id) or any other parameter.

Does anyone know if this is supported by Rest API?

I have found some limited XMLRPC api "filtering" options, but none on REST. Any help would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such method apparently. 
Solved it by adding ?overload=medium, which will fetch all sites from OpenX and then in my client iterate through list of sites and compare account_id.